# C++11 how to pass data to a running thread

Tags: multithreading, c++11

Say I use async to call a function in a separate thread and function waits for the input data (data comes with interval of 2-3sec). Can I pass the data to the function running in a separate thread? For example:

```
 void f(int x) { std::cout << "x: " << x << std::endl;}

 int main() {
     int x = get_x();
     std::async(std::launch::asunc, f, x);
     while(true) {
        x = get_x();
        //update x and sleep 2 sec
     }
 }
```

Comment: What happens when you actually try this?

Comment: @YePhIcK I suppose the function always prints the first x value, wouldn't it?

Comment: I was mostly pointing out that the code wouldn't even compile (much less run) which shows lack of research for posting a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send data into another thread using any of the multitude of techniques, from shared memory to messages (both IPC and RPC), to file on disk... You can find the one that suites your needs if you google for "producer-consumer pattern". Here's one such article on MSDN [How to: Implement Various Producer-Consumer Patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728068.aspx).

As for the question in the form that you are asking the answer is **you cannot**. Even though you can definitely call the function with the parameter value of your choice, this **will not** somehow magically update the internal state of the already running function somewhere on another thread. What this will do - it will... call the function and wait for it to finish and return back to the caller (as expected).